# Undefined subroutine when moving a file

Tags: perl, move

My current directory is composed in this way:

```
currentDirectory
 - folder1
   -file1
 - folder2
```

In code I wrote to move *file1 to folder2* this according to the [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) doc:

```
move("folder1/file1","folder2/file1");
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::move at script.pl line 49
```

Comment: it is the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you either forgot to include the module with [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Copy;

move("folder1/file1","folder2/file1");
```

Or you have something like:

```
use File::Copy qw();
```

Comment: god bless you, i saw a lot of, but i forgot use `File::copy`